# Logical schema development and migration tool for different physical schema available including triggers and stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-design, tools, migration

We are planning to support for our application another rdbms (oracle).

At the moment we are design our database schema with the MySQL-Workbench. For every new database version we have

- schema er-diagram
- a full schema sql script (create table.., create index..., create trigger..., ...)
- and a migrate sql script (alter table...., drop index, create index..., ...)
- and finally a data file which all in it (*.mwb file)

We use table, index, stored routines, views and triggers. We want a tool, where we can design the table, relations, views, triggers and routines and export a full schema sql script for different rdbms **and** an migration sql skipt to upgrade a database for different rdbms.

Now my question. Is the any tool available, which is able to do the above stuff for both MySQL and Oracle?

I look at *AnySQL Maestro*, *Navicat Premion*, *Altova DatabaseSpy* but all loose information (mostly the triggers). I found also this [wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools), but i can't figure out, which have the feature we need.

EDIT: clarification:

*Atilla Ozgur* (see his answer) is right. A want a tool whit a logical model including triggers and procedure and which is able to export all the things (especially triggers and routines) to different (at the moment MySQL and Oracle) physical models. The export should be done by sql scripts.

Comment: You do understand that the procedural language(s)/capabilities are totally different between MySQL and Oracle? There is no automatic way of converting one to the other if that is what you are after.

Comment: I'm aware of this. But is it real impossible to design also triggers in meta logical schema and translate this in different physical layer languages? I don't want to convert the schema between mysql and oracle. I just can't believe that we must design and migrate always two logical schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I have used it (but that's a long time ago) Sybase PowerDesigner was able to handle triggers and procedures for all supported DBMS.

Looking at the current manuals, that still seems to be the case.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38058.1600/doc/html/rad1232020719541.html

Although I don't see MySQL mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

You want to be able to design and develop following objects.

- table
- index
- stored routines
- views
- triggers.

Modelling tools will be able to help you with table, views and indexes. These tools are called with different names. Entity Relationship tools, Database Diagram, Database Modelling tools.

Some examples are :

- http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio
- http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/

You will design your data model, logical model, using these tools. After that you will export your physical model to different databases. Something like below.

```
1 logical
  1 physical Oracle
  1 physical Mysql
  1 physical Sql Server
```

I do not know if there exists any tool which will be able to help you write stored procedures and triggers in one place and export them to different databases. These change from database to database a lot. Sql server uses TSQL for trigger and stored procedures. Oracle uses PLSQL

Comment: Thanx for the answers, but i definitely asked for tool which able to export triggers and procedures to different physical models. I probably update my question.

Comment: your title: "Schema development and migration tool for multiple rdbms (mysql, oracle) available" suggest otherwise.

Comment: Atilla Ozgur: thanks for your advice. I updated the title.

Comment: I think "development and migration tool for multiple rdbms, especially trigger and stored procedures" something along these lines may be better. Since you said " i definitely asked for tool which able to export triggers and procedures to different physical models."